# Cursor always empty Android SQLite. Cannot find column?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to return a string from a database, but for some reason it looks as if the cursor cannot find the Column? I think?

This is the code im having problems with:

```
Cursor resultSet = myDbHelper.findUser(userName);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();
    String result="";

    TextView t1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    boolean a = (resultSet != null);
    boolean b = (resultSet.moveToFirst());

    if(resultSet != null && resultSet.moveToFirst())
    {
        result = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        t1.setText("String= "+result);
    }
```

And this is the helper method that is being called:

```
public Cursor findUser(String uName)
{
    Cursor res = myDatabase.query("Person WHERE Name = '"+uName+"';",
            null,null,null,null,null,null);
    return res;
}
```

For some reason when im debugging the app the boolean variables i have created A becomes True and B stays false, so i know it must be an issue with the Cursor moveToFirst, but i dont know whats up?  the String result also remains empty.

Can anyone help me where im going wrong.  The column in the DataBase is called Name, from the Person table.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `query(...)` method with all the parameters filled in properly? Take a look in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) under the query method.

Comment: Because im just trying to pull one string at the minute, this is the first time ive ever worked with sqlite. So at the minute i just want a string, which i cant even do

Comment: If `resultSet.moveToFirst()` returns false then the query did not find any matching records for your query. Are you sure the case is the same for `uName` between when you look up the name and when you save it?

Comment: Yeah its definitely the same unless there is a problem with spaces?? thats all i can think

Comment: Try to temporarily remove the ` WHERE Name = '"+uName+"';` and just select everything to see if you get a record then. Then you at least know it's an issue with the restriction. If that works I would convert it to use the `query(...)` method properly passing in the restriction parameters in the correct place.

Comment: Yes that worked, but from some reason it i using old database data??  I have updated the the whole database with actual data and its still pulling old test data for some reason???